# Unable to install Resharper 10.0.2 with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, installation, resharper

I am trying to install [Resharper 10.0.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/) with VS 2013, I have completed the setup but still unable to see any menu item related to Resharper also found nothing in tools > options. I am running Windows 7.

I wants to rename my files and master pages in my running project with all references. I have read that resharper will do it properly, is there any other way or help me installing Resharper.

Comment: Check the status of ReSharper extention in `Tools - Extentions and Updates`

Comment: Have you tried the steps from the following article https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241845-ReSharper-is-not-available-in-Visual-Studio-after-installation like checking  availability of files or removing the registry branch?